# Automake fails when trying to run platform-specific build

Tags: makefile, autoconf, automake

I am using autotools to build a project that I want to cross-compile for both Linus and Mac OSX. I am building two libraries, `libevent.la` and `libaffinity.la`. `libevent` should be build when automake is run on both platform. However, `libaffinity.la` should be build only if the platform is MACOSX. To this end, I have the following in my `configure.ac` file:

```
#Detect the target system
case "$host_os" in
    darwin*)
        build_darwin=yes
        ;;
esac

AM_CONDITIONAL([DARWIN], [test "$build_darwin" = "yes"])
```

The variable`DARWIN` will be set if the proejct is being build on Mac OS. And in the `Makefile.am` I have following:

```
extlibdir = $(libdir)/guile/$(GUILE_EFFECTIVE_VERSION)/extensions
extlib_LTLIBRARIES = libevent.la
AM_CFLAGS = -I$(srcdir) $(WARN_CFLAGS) $(DEBUG_CFLAGS) 
libevent_la_SOURCES = libevent.c
libevent_la_CFLAGS = $(AM_CFLAGS) $(GUILE_CFLAGS) -Wno-error -Wno-nullability-completeness -Wno-expansion-to-defined
libevent_la_LIBADD = $(GUILE_LIBS)
libevent_la_LDFLAGS = -export-dynamic -module
$(GOBJECTS): libevent.la

if DARWIN
    extlib_LTLIBRARIES += libaffinity.la
    affinity_la_SOURCES = affinity.c
    affinity_la_CFLAGS = $(AM_CFLAGS) $(GUILE_CFLAGS) -Wno-error -Wno-nullability-completeness -Wno-expansion-to-defined
    affinity_la_LIBADD = $(GUILE_LIBS)
    affinity_la_LDFLAGS = -export-dynamic -module
    $(GOBJECTS) += libaffinity.la
endif
```

When I run `make`, it fails with the following error:

> extlib_LTLIBRARIES += affinity.la
>
> make[1]: extlib_LTLIBRARIES: No such file or directory
>
> make: *** [all] Error 2

However, as you can see, **extlib_LTLIBRARIES** is defined above the if statement.

How can I fix this? Or is there a better way to do this so that I can selectively build `libaffinity.la` based on the platform?

Comment: I don't think this is responsible for the issue you describe, but start with changing the name of artifact to be conditionally built to be `libaffinity.la`, not `affinity.la`.

Comment: The lines inside the conditional in your `Makefile.am` are indented.  You are not by any chance using a tab character for that, are you?  Even if you didn't mean to do that, it would be worthwhile to make sure that your editor didn't sub in tabs in place of runs of spaces.  Upon reflection, I think this is a pretty good candidate for the nature of the error.  The error message is consistent with `make` interpreting the indented lines as (part of) the recipe for a rule.

Comment: @JohnBollinger. Removing the tabs fixed the issue! So does this mean tabs introduce some sort of new scope in automake?

Comment: Almost everything in a `Makefile.am` is carried forward ultimately to a `Makefile` that is processed by `make`.  It is to `make` -- which after all is what reported an error -- that tabs are significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem turns out to have been that the lines in the conditional section were indented with tabs.  These are not particularly significant to Automake, but they will have been carried through to its generated `Makefile.in`, and, from there, to the `Makefile` generated by `configure`.  Tabs *are* significant to `make`: a leading tab is how `make` recognizes the lines of a rule's recipe.  (Only a tab will do; spaces do not have the same significance.)

The effect, then, was that `make` interpreted `extlib_LTLIBRARIES += libaffinity.la` as one of the commands in the recipe for some rule, so that when it tried to apply the rule, it wanted to execute a system command named `extlib_LTLIBRARIES`.  There being no such executable command found in the path, the shell failed and reported "No such file or directory", which message `make` forwarded on to its own output.

The fix is to avoid indenting with tabs in your `Makefile.am` (spaces are ok), except where you actually intend to write a recipe for a `make` rule (for which an initial tab is obligatory).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the answer!